# Is there a python-alembic way to convert data between dropping and adding a column?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a `sqlite3` database accessing it with `SQLAlchemy` in `python3`.
I want to add a new and drop an old column with the database-migation tool `alembic`. Simple example:

```
class Model(_Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Model'
  _oid = Column('oid', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  _number_int = sa.Column('number_int', sa.Integer)
```

Should be after migration like this:

```
class Model(_Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Model'
  _oid = Column('oid', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  _number_str = sa.Column('number_str', sa.String(length=30))
```

The relevant point here is that there is data in `_number_int` that should be converted into `_number_str` like this:

```
number_conv = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
_number_str = number_conv[_number_int]
```

Is there an **alembic way** to take care of that? It means if alembic itself take care of cases like that in its concept/design?
I want to know If I can use alembic tools for that or if I have to do my own extra code for that.

Of course the original data is a little bit more complex to convert. This is just an example here.

Comment: Like this https://julo.ch/blog/migrating-content-with-alembic/ ?

Comment: Thanks. This is the way I would have done this, too. But it is not an *alembic way* in the meaning of fitting to the alembic concept. It might be that the alembic concept/design doesn't take care of cases like that?

Comment: Alembic has [method](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html?highlight=bulk_insert#alembic.operations.Operations.bulk_insert) to insert data. But it doesn't have anything built-in for data updates. So I think do it yourself is the right way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is alembic [operation reference](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html). There is a method called [`bulk_insert()`](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.bulk_insert) for bulk inserting content, but nothing for migrating existing content. It seems alembic doesn't have it built-in. But you can implement data migration yourself.

One possible approach is described in the article ["Migrating content with alembic"](https://julo.ch/blog/migrating-content-with-alembic/). You need to define intermediate table inside your migration file, which contains both columns (`number_int` and `number_str`):

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

model_helper = sa.Table(
    'Model',
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('oid', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('number_int', sa.Integer),
    sa.Column('number_str', sa.String(length=30)),
)
```

And use this intermediate table to migrate data from old column to the new one:

```
from alembic import op


def upgrade():
    # add the new column first
    op.add_column(
        'Model',
        sa.Column(
            'number_str',
            sa.String(length=30),
            nullable=True
        )
    )

    # build a quick link for the current connection of alembic
    connection = op.get_bind()

    # at this state right now, the old column is not deleted and the
    # new columns are present already. So now is the time to run the
    # content migration. We use the connection to grab all data from
    # the table, convert each number and update the row, which is 
    # identified by its id
    number_conv = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
    for item in connection.execute(model_helper.select()):
        connection.execute(
            model_helper.update().where(
                model_helper.c.id == item.id
            ).values(
                number_str=number_conv[item.number_int]
            )
        )

    # now that all data is migrated we can just drop the old column
    # without having lost any data
    op.drop_column('Model', 'number_int')
```

This approach is a bit noisy (you need to define table manually), but it works.